# Problems saving several pdf files in R

Tags: r, pdf, save

I'm trying to save several xyplots created with a "for" loop in R and I'm not able to get complete pdf files (all files have the same size and I can't open them) if I execute the following loop:

```
for (i in 1:length(gases.names)) {
   # Set ylim;
   r_y <- round(range(ratio.cal[,i][ratio.cal[,i]<999], na.rm = T), digits = 1);
   r_y <- c(r_y[1]-0.1, r_y[2]+0.1);

   outputfile <- paste (path, "/cal_ratio_",gases.names[i], ".pdf", sep="");
   dev.new();
   xyplot(ratio.cal[,i] ~ data.GC.all$data.time, groups = data.vial, panel = 
      panel.superpose, xlab = "Date", ylab = gases.names[i], xaxt="n", ylim = r_y);
   savePlot(filename = outputfile, type = 'pdf', device = dev.cur());
   dev.off();
}
```

(a previous version was using `trellis.device()` instead of `dev.new() + savePlot()`)

Do you know why I can't get good pdf files? If I do it "manually" it works... Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

use `pdf` directly

```
for (i in seq_along(gases.names)) {
  # Set ylim
  r_y <- round(range(ratio.cal[,i][ratio.cal[,i]<999], na.rm = T), digits = 1)
  r_y <- c(r_y[1]-0.1, r_y[2]+0.1)

   outputfile <- paste (path, "/cal_ratio_",gases.names[i], ".pdf", sep="")
   pdf(file = outputfile, width = 7, height = 7)
   print(xyplot(ratio.cal[,i] ~ data.GC.all$data.time, groups = data.vial, 
                 panel =  panel.superpose, xlab = "Date", ylab = gases.names[i], 
                 xaxt="n", ylim = r_y))

  dev.off()

}
```

Comment: Note the use of `print`, related to this most frequent of [FAQ's](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-lattice_002ftrellis-graphics-not-work_003f).