# Why are my plots not written to disk?

Tags: r

Is there any reason why my plots are not getting written to disk? I am saving my plots according to [this description](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/saving.html) but it is not working. Each plot is just a white image. Why is that so?

Here is the full script I am using;

```
library(rAltmetric)
library(aRxiv)

print('Load DOIs ..')

doi_list <- list()

categ <- c(AP = 'cat:stat.AP',
           CO = "cat:stat.CO", # I'm naming these elements so
           ME = "cat:stat.ME", # that the corresponding elements
           TH = "cat:stat.TH", # in the list are named as well.
           ML = "cat:stat.ML") # Could also just set 'names(doi_list)' to 'categ'.

doi_list <- 
  lapply(categ, function(ctg)
    (doi <- arxiv_search(ctg)$doi)[nchar(doi) > 0])

print('Showing altmetrics ..')

num = 0

for(category in doi_list) {

  for(mydoi in category) {
    print(paste('Searching DOI:', mydoi))

    #acuna <- altmetrics(doi=mydoi)
    acuna <- altmetrics(doi="10.1038/489201a")

    if(is.null(acuna)) {
      next
    }

    print(acuna)

    acuna_data <- altmetric_data(acuna)
    jpeg(filename=paste(num, ".jpg", sep=""))
    plot(acuna, main=paste(num, ".jpg", sep=""))
    dev.off()
    num <- num + 1
  }
}

print('All done.')
```

Comment: If it is like xyplot, you may try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114594/problems-saving-several-pdf-files-in-r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is [R FAQ 7.22](http://www.hep.by/gnu/r-patched/r-faq/R-FAQ_73.html),

> 7.22 Why do lattice/trellis graphics not work?

The most likely reason is that you forgot to tell R to display the graph. Lattice functions such as `xyplot()` create a graph object, but do not display it (the same is true of `ggplot2` graphics, and Trellis graphics in S-PLUS). The `print()` method for the graph object produces the actual display. When you use these functions interactively at the command line, the result is automatically printed, but in `source()` or inside your own functions you will need an explicit `print()` statement.

Use

```
print(plot(acuna, main=paste(num, ".jpg", sep="")))
```